# Brahmotsavam in Tirupati only and not in other divyadesams

Tags: venkateshwara, tirupati

Why [Brahmotsavam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srivari_Brahmotsavam) is celebrated in Tirupati in Aswayuja or Asvin or Purattasi month? Why not in other 105 Divyadesams? Any puranic reference.

Comment: Brahmotsavam is celebrated in all Vishnu temples.  It originates from the god Brahma organizing a festival to honor the wedding of Venkateshwara and Padmavathi.  Let me try to find a scriptural reference for it:

Comment: Even i'm searching Scriptural sources.

Comment: This is the reason i suggested you long ago to ask main question in **heading** instead of making vague sentences such as "Bramhostavam in Tirupati".

Comment: I cannot change my way--People who think brilliant have to modify by referring the body of the question---this is niot happening--according to their thinking they change the question--